# How to make Django sessionId cookie as secure

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

This is my current `sessionId` cookie attributes:

> Set-Cookie: sessionid=3jdpjxgepk49vrnhbabdvju3r80ci581; expires=Mon, 06-Aug-2018 12:40:14 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/

I want `sessionId` to be secure with the `secure` attribute:

> Set-Cookie: sessionid=3jdpjxgepk49vrnhbabdvju3r80ci581; expires=Mon, 06-Aug-2018 12:40:14 GMT; HttpOnly,secure; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/

I have tried adding the following attribute in `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

However, I am still not getting the `secure` attribute in `sessionId`.
Any alternative solution for this?

Comment: please, write more details what did you mean `it doesn't work for me`?

Comment: Hi Bear Brown - I have just add few more details. Could you help me with those details.

Comment: maybe the question help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861784/django-csrf-cookie-httponly

Answer (score 13):

1. Verify if your settings file is [properly configured](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/)
2. Set the `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in the settings file
3. You can test the changes by [running your Django application in the interactive Shell](https://www.csestack.org/open-python-shell-django/) to check if the variable got changed:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE # it should be printing "True"
```

**Important:** If you are running the application over HTTP instead of HTTPS (which is usually the case on our local machines) even with that variable set to true the session cookie will not get encrypted. It just works over HTTPS connections.

Comment: We are on AWS behind a load balancer. The traffic to the load balancer is over HTTPS but from the load balancer to EC2 instances it's HTTP. I already have SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True but the PCI scan gave me the "insecure cookies" warning. I think the "Important" note part of your answer explains this. Any ideas about what can I do? @fabriciorissetto

Comment: I deploy my local development server with HTTPS (with `runserver_plus` from the `django-extensions` package) for this exact reason: `./manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt`. Browsers complain but it's a great sandbox to test in.

Comment: @gurel_kaynak I just found out about this. You should configure your reverse proxy or load balancer to add a header to the request, and set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
 in Django to the same value. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header